# Communication between C# and C++ application

Tags: c#, c++, wcf

I have just start learning about `WCF` that can help me for the communication between two different platform application. I have also created one simple application for the communication but both client and service are written in C#. I want to know how I can establish a `C++` and `C#` application so that they communicate to each other. Thanks in advance

Comment: Both c++ and c# client app can communicate through the service ( WCF service or web API).
you also can use c++ lib in C# app (but it's not recommended).

Comment: *How to communicate between the two applications* seems too vague. There're so many ways to do so, and thus it's hard to answer in a specific manner.

Answer (score 0):

this question seems very wide to me, the thing is since you are in windows, and the C# and C++ applicattions will be running simultaneously, you have to thing in the specific requeriments of you appliccation.

For example, I had a Server in C# wich recived some data, that had to be processed in C++ and then returned to the sender, so, since the C# and C++ process were in the same computer I used a File Mapping method, for example.

Indepently of the language, what you have to make sure, is that the data you send, wen you recive it in the other process, that should be able to be understood.

Here is a link for more info in wnidows
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx